# Recover encrypted /home folder in Linux Mint

Tags: linux-mint, home

I'm trying to recover my personnal folder (/home/userfloflo) from an old installation of linux mint which doesn't boot anymore.
I'm trying to retrieve this folder with a linux mint live usb.

When i navigate in /home/userfloflo I have two files :

1. Access-Your-Private-Data.desktop
2. README.txt

**README.TXT**

> THIS DIRECTORY HAS BEEN UNMOUNTED TO PROTECT YOUR DATA.
>
> From the graphical desktop, click on:  "Access Your Private Data"
>
> or
>
> From the command line, run:  ecryptfs-mount-private

The problem is that

```
ecryptfs-mount-private
```

returns

```
ERROR: Encrypted private directory is not setup properly
```

and

```
ecryptfs-recover-private
```

returns

```
INFO: Searching for encrypted private directories (this might take a while)...
find: ‘/run/user/999/gvfs’: Permission denied
```

**UPDATE**

```
ls -lA
```

returns

```
 total 4
lrwxrwxrwx 1 1000 1000   56 May 13 19:58 Access-Your-Private-Data.desktop -> /usr/share/ecryptfs-utils/ecryptfs-mount-private.desktop
drwx------ 3 1000 1000 4096 May 13 19:59 .cache
lrwxrwxrwx 1 1000 1000   33 May 13 19:58 .ecryptfs -> /home/.ecryptfs/florian/.ecryptfs
lrwxrwxrwx 1 1000 1000   32 May 13 19:58 .Private -> /home/.ecryptfs/florian/.Private
lrwxrwxrwx 1 1000 1000   52 May 13 19:58 README.txt -> /usr/share/ecryptfs-utils/ecryptfs-mount-private.txt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see from these two directory entries:

> ```
> lrwxrwxrwx 1 1000 1000   33 May 13 19:58 .ecryptfs -> /home/.ecryptfs/florian/.ecryptfs
> lrwxrwxrwx 1 1000 1000   32 May 13 19:58 .Private -> /home/.ecryptfs/florian/.Private
> ```

the encrypted directory you're trying to access is embedded inside the encrypted directory for `/home`, which covers all users.

First of all you're going to need to get that directory unencrypted. Once you've done that you should be able to get to the encrypted directory for `userfloflo` and you can unencrypt that.

Unfortunately, nested encryption doesn't really add any extra security, but it does add considerable complexity.